# Salvage "How can I keep myself valuable"

Tags: discussion, specific-question, reopen-request

I find this question ([How can I keep myself valuable to deliver in my work if more and more stuffs are automated in data science?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/89505/47387)) quite interesting, despite currently having a very strong advice aspect, which makes it off-topic. I think we may be able to salvage it.

Instead of focussing on "what should I do", I think we may be able to turn it into something like:

> Coming from the technical world, what are the aspects that make me valuable to my company? Currently my work is being automated and I definitely think I'm losing value to my company.

The first part "Coming from the technical world" may not be necessary but I think it may be useful to keep the question properly scoped and not getting too wide.

Any thoughts about this?

A part of the answer would be obviously the visibility, but I don't want the question to focus on this, as it has already been well covered on the workplace.

Comment: This is a pretty related (duplicate?) question to that one - https://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/77055/2322

Comment: I think as asked, it would cover from a higher level than just a discussion with your current boss. I don't know if it'll make worth the question to stand on its own though. But maybe the answer for the question I suggest would be "discuss with your boss -> see [link]"